# How to use mongoexport to export collection in database via Node.js and child_process or mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, child-process

I am new to MongoDB and am having a difficult time exporting an existing collection as a single JSON file. I can successfully connect to my mLab database. I've been scouring the documentation for node, mongoose, and mongodb, as well as searching stackoverflow. I have not found a concise answer. How do I either use a child process or mongoose to perform a mongoexport?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var options = {server: {socketOptions: {keepAlive:300000, connecTimeoutMS:30000}},
               replset:{socketOptions: {keepAlive:300000, connectTimeoutMS:30000}}};

var mongodbUri = 'My mongodb database Uri here';
mongoose.connect(mongodbUri,options);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function(){
});

console.log('made it through successfully');

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('mongoexport', ['--db', 'db', '--collection','events']).stdout.pipe(process.stdout);


mongoose.connection.close();
```

I am getting a throw error with my current code. My collection is named events, and I need all of the documents within it in one JSON object.